# Finding the $(n*m)$th element in a sequence without multiples of $n$ or $m$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $S(x,y)$ be the sequence of positive integers without any multiples of $x$ or $y$.  For example, $S(4,7)$ would be:

```
1,2,3,5,6,9,10,11,13,15,17...
```

Now, let $F(x,y)$ be the $(x*y)$th element of the $S(x,y)$ sequence.  Using the above example, $F(4,7)$ would be $41$.

I'm looking for a formula to calculate $F(x,y)$ without actually generating the entire sequence.  What would that formula be, or does none exist?

Comment: It seems challenging, not easy. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, I think it is challenging.

Comment: I think the answer will vary depending on whether $x$ and $y$ are co - primes or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n$ be a positive integer .Let's count how many numbers from $S(x,y)$ are up to $n$ .

Let $l=lcm(x,y)$ .There are $\lfloor \frac{n}{x} \rfloor$ numbers divisible with $x$ , $\lfloor \frac{n}{y} \rfloor$ divisible with $y$ and $\lfloor \frac{n}{l} \rfloor$ divisible with both $x$ and $y$ .

From a simple PIE argument there are 
$$n-\lfloor \frac{n}{x} \rfloor-\lfloor \frac{n}{y} \rfloor+\lfloor \frac{n}{l} \rfloor$$ numbers in $S(x,y)$ up to $n$ .

Now use the fact that $F(x,y)$ is the **minimal** number $n$ such that there are $xy$ numbers up to $n$ in $S(x,y)$ .

So we found that :

$F(x,y)$ is the minimal solution of the equation :

$$n-\lfloor \frac{n}{x} \rfloor-\lfloor \frac{n}{y} \rfloor+\lfloor \frac{n}{l} \rfloor=xy$$

I don't think there's a simple formula for this .

Comment: Damn, you beat me to this while I was wondering whether there was a simple formula :P note that Mathematica can somehow calculate it: `InverseFunction[ With[{x = 4, 
    y = 7}, # - (Floor@(#/x) + Floor@(#/y) - Floor@(#/(x y)))] &][28]`

Comment: Bizarre, I agree with this solution without to understand it. I´ll try. You have a future ComplexPhi.Congratulations.